# Can't display data in ListView using Retrofit

Tags: java, android, listview, retrofit

I 've problem with display data in ListView. I get data from Retrofit response, but my activity, which should display this data, is just beeing blank, all the time. I am sure, that I've receiving data, I've checked it, in console.

Model class

```
public class itemList_model {
@SerializedName("results")
private List<itemList_Results> results;

public List<itemList_Results> getResults() {
    return results;
}

public static class itemList_Results{
    @SerializedName("title")
    String title;
    @SerializedName("vote_average")
    Double vote;
    @SerializedName("genre_ids")
    List<Integer> genresId;
    @SerializedName("release_date")
    String releaseDate;

    public itemList_Results(String title, Double vote, String releaseDate) {
        this.title = title;
        this.vote = vote;
        this.releaseDate = releaseDate;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public Double getVote() {
        return vote;
    }

    public List<Integer> getGenresId() {
        return genresId;
    }

    public String getReleaseDate() {
        return releaseDate;
    }
}

public class itemList_genresId{
    @SerializedName("genre_ids")
    int id;

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }
 }
}
```

adapter class

```
public class genres_adapter extends ArrayAdapter<itemList_model.itemList_Results> {
RetrofitCalls calls;

public genres_adapter(@NonNull Context context, ArrayList<itemList_model.itemList_Results> list) {
    super(context, 0, list);
}

@NonNull
@Override
public View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
    View itemView = convertView;
    if (itemView == null){
        itemView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.genres_item_view, parent, false);
    }
    itemList_model.itemList_Results model = getItem(position);

    TextView title = itemView.findViewById(R.id.title);
    title.setText(model.getTitle());
    TextView vote = itemView.findViewById(R.id.vote);
    vote.setText(String.valueOf(model.getVote()));
    TextView release = itemView.findViewById(R.id.release);
    release.setText(model.getReleaseDate());
    return itemView;
 }
}
```

activity java class

```
ArrayList<itemList_model.itemList_Results> arrayList;
genres_adapter adapter;

String title = "";
Double average_votes = 0.0;
String date = "";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_genres_list_view);

    arrayList = new ArrayList<itemList_model.itemList_Results>();
    adapter = new genres_adapter(this, arrayList);

    ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.genres_listView);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    getListViewItems();
}
public void getListViewItems(){

    String url = "https://api.themoviedb.org/";
    Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(url)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build();

    apiCall api = retrofit.create(apiCall.class);
    Call<itemList_model> call = api.getHorror();
    call.enqueue(new Callback<itemList_model>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<itemList_model> call, Response<itemList_model> response) {
            if (!response.isSuccessful()) {
                Log.i(TAG, "onResponse: " + response.code());
            }
            List<itemList_model.itemList_Results> list = response.body().getResults();
            for (itemList_model.itemList_Results model : list){

                title =model.getTitle();
                average_votes = Double.valueOf(model.getVote());
                date =model.getReleaseDate();
            }
            list.add(new itemList_model.itemList_Results(title,average_votes,date));
        }
        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<itemList_model> call, Throwable t) {
            Log.i(TAG, "onFailure: "+t.getMessage());
        }
    });
}
```

- activity, that contains ListView, is called activity_genres_list_view
- activity which will be used by adapter, is called genres_item_view

I'm guess, it's about data from list, maybe it's not being added?

Comment: please check my answer

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, you should add your list to adapter after you received it:

```
adapter.addAll(list);
```

Answer (score 1):

I cannot see any `notifyDataSetChanged()` call in your code. When the response is found from the `Retrofit` call, you need to update the list which was passed to the adapter and call `notifyDataSetChanged` on your adapter to see the effect.

Hence you might consider doing something like the following.

```
public void getListViewItems(){

    String url = "https://api.themoviedb.org/";
    Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(url)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build();

    apiCall api = retrofit.create(apiCall.class);
    Call<itemList_model> call = api.getHorror();
    call.enqueue(new Callback<itemList_model>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<itemList_model> call, Response<itemList_model> response) {
            if (!response.isSuccessful()) {
                Log.i(TAG, "onResponse: " + response.code());
            }

            // Do not create a new list here. Use the arrayList which was declared before and passed to the adapter
            // List<itemList_model.itemList_Results> list = response.body().getResults();

            // Clear the arrayList before pushing new data
            arrayList.clear();

            for (itemList_model.itemList_Results model : list){
                title =model.getTitle();
                average_votes = Double.valueOf(model.getVote());
                date = model.getReleaseDate();

                // Add the data into the arrayList instead of the list
                arrayList.add(new itemList_model.itemList_Results(title,average_votes,date));
            }

            // Now call notifyDataSetChanged on your adapter to see the changes in the ListView
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<itemList_model> call, Throwable t) {
            Log.i(TAG, "onFailure: "+t.getMessage());
        }
    });
}
```

Hope that fixes your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing appear because you are setting adapter before getting information :

```
    adapter = new genres_adapter(this, arrayList);//array list is still empty here
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    getListViewItems();
```

what yo should do is setting adapter once you get the list ! or call `notifydatasetChanged` on your adapter after you get your informations !

```
{
.....
arrayList.add(new itemList_model.itemList_Results(title,average_votes,date));
.....
}
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```